# Linux text: add line to previous line of a pattern

Tags: linux, file, text

I would like to add a specific line "TER" to several variable text files:

Input:

```
[...]
ATOM   4149  C   LEU C   9     136.820 120.050  53.540  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4150  O   LEU C   9     136.600 118.860  53.240  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4151  O   LEU C   9     137.310 120.340  54.650  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4154  N   LYS D   2     115.050 134.940  61.060  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4155  H1  LYS D   2     115.660 134.160  61.180  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4156  H2  LYS D   2     114.760 135.000  60.100  1.00  0.00
[...]
```

Output:

```
[...]
ATOM   4149  C   LEU C   9     136.820 120.050  53.540  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4150  O   LEU C   9     136.600 118.860  53.240  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4151  O   LEU C   9     137.310 120.340  54.650  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM   4154  N   LYS D   2     115.050 134.940  61.060  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4155  H1  LYS D   2     115.660 134.160  61.180  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4156  H2  LYS D   2     114.760 135.000  60.100  1.00  0.00
[...]
```

So the pattern is: if after a " C " for the first time a " D " is found add a "TER" before the " D " line (after the " C " line). All other numbers and characters can be variable.

I found some examples with the sed command however I do not know how to do add to the previous line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'last_c5=="C" && $5=="D" {print "TER"}; last_c5=$5' file
ATOM   4149  C   LEU C   9     136.820 120.050  53.540  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4150  O   LEU C   9     136.600 118.860  53.240  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4151  O   LEU C   9     137.310 120.340  54.650  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM   4154  N   LYS D   2     115.050 134.940  61.060  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4155  H1  LYS D   2     115.660 134.160  61.180  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4156  H2  LYS D   2     114.760 135.000  60.100  1.00  0.00
```

It keeps tracking last 5th column value storing it in `last_c5` variable. In case the previous was `C` and the current is `D`, it prints `TER`. On `last_c5=$5` all lines are being printed.

Comment: Just one more question: wẂhy is "awk 'last_c5=="\ C\ " && $5=="\ D\ " {print "TER"}; last_c5=$5' test.txt" or "awk 'last_c5==" C " && $5==" D " {print "TER"}; last_c5=$5' test.txt" not working? To be on the save side I would like to include the whitespaces before and after the C and D.

Comment: @user2952361 because the space does not belong to the column. `$5` refers to the 5th field, and the grouping is done by space as delimiter. The comparison is done so that just `C` and `D` will match, don't have to worry.